# Why is my simple page navigation failing with a TargetInvocationException?

Tags: c#, navigation, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8, invocationtargetexception

My app is failing at the "Debugger.Break" here:

```
private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

...and I get: "*System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll*"

My code is very simple so far. I simply have a HyperlinkButton on the main page that tries to navigate to another page:

```
//winrt-xaml:
        <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hyperlinkButtonManageInvitations" Margin="24" Grid.Row="1" Tap="HyperlinkButtonManageInvitations_OnTap">Manage Invitations</HyperlinkButton>
```

//C# code-behind:

```
private void HyperlinkButtonManageInvitations_OnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(
        new Uri("//TaSLs_Pages/InvitationManagePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

I did use Resharper to move MainPage.xaml (and *.cs) into my TaSLs_Pages subfolder; that wouldn't be a problem, would it?

Comment: does the error come when you hit the Hyperlink Button?  Or when starting the app?

Comment: It's before the Hyperlink button is pressed; I put a breakpoint there, and it's not reached.

Comment: I used Resharper to move MainPage back up out of my "Pages" subfolder, and the main page now displays again. However, I still get to Debugger.Break, first in RootFrame_NavigationFailed() and then Application_UnhandledException().

Comment: When you moved the MainPage, I suspect Resharper isn't aware that the WMAppManifest.xml needs to be updated to reflect the path to the new Navigation Page... now that you've moved it back though, unsure.  When you get Debugger.Break, check the Exception property of the argument 'e' in NavigationFailed, that should have more salient information for you.

Comment: Got it working, thanks, Jim; it ended up being a stinkin' typo in my page name! argghhh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check NavigationFailedEventArgs. You can check the exception by e.Exception.Message